# How do I drag a jQuery slider handle from within Capybara and ChromeDriver?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to execute the following code to move the slider handle, but the events triggered in the browser are not taking place.

```
page.execute_script(%Q($('#slider_handicap').slider('values',1,30)))
```

That correctly sets the right handle to 30, but I need it to behave as if I were actually taking the mouse and dragging the handle to 30 then releasing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I extended capybara dragging before.
It can move elements by a given offset.

You could try

```
module CapybaraExtension
  def drag_by(right_by, down_by)
    base.drag_by(right_by, down_by)
  end
end

module CapybaraSeleniumExtension
  def drag_by(right_by, down_by)
    resynchronize { driver.browser.action.drag_and_drop_by(native, right_by, down_by).perform }
  end
end

::Capybara::Selenium::Node.send :include, CapybaraSeleniumExtension
::Capybara::Node::Element.send :include, CapybaraExtension
```

And then

```
page.find('#slider_handicap').drag_by(30, 0)
```

But it may not suit the slider's scale.

The original are

- [Capybara::Node::Element#drag_to](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/element.rb)
- [Capybara::Selenium::Node#drag_to](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb)
- Selenium:: WebDriver::ActionBuilder drag_and_drop and drag_and_drop_by

There are a few words of caution.

- This extension could depend on the type of driver and the version of
  driver.
- This kind of test with dragging could lead to difficulty of maintainance.

Answer (score 14):

resynchronize has been removed from Capybara 2.0 so user853088's answer for Selenium would now look like this:

```
module CapybaraSeleniumExtension
  def drag_by(right_by, down_by)
    driver.browser.action.drag_and_drop_by(native, right_by, down_by).perform
  end
end
```