# Capybara fill_in for HTML5 input range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, rspec, capybara

I'm implementing a basic slider using the new HTML5 input type of Range.
No javascript or CSS involved.

Here's an example [HTML5 input-type Range](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range)

It used to be a text box so in Capybara I could just say

```
fill_in "rating_scale", with: "57"
```

Now I need a way to tell it to fill_in the range or to click and move the range's thumb.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: Not necessarily a nice way to do it, but you could directly modify the input's value to fake it being used.

Comment: If that ended up working, you should set it as an answer so other people will know how to fix the issue should it happen to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the slider is using Javascript so you will need a driver for Capybara to interact with Javascript, like [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist).

Comment: The js isn't necessary for setting the input element's value via the DOM api.

Answer (score 5):

That is what I ended up doing...

```
find(:xpath, "//input[@id='rating_scale']").set 57
```

Comment: If you need the change event to fire, then after calling `.set(57)`, call `.trigger('input')`. Adding this comment because google kept bringing up this thread, and I was trying everything here, but it never worked because I'm trying to test action that is triggered by changing a slider value (e.g. a debounced save).

Comment: `trigger('input')` didn't work for me with phantomjs, says _unknown event_

Comment: `find(".some-css-class").set(57).trigger('input')` worked perfectly in my ReactJS component. It cause the `onChange()` event listener to actually trigger

Answer (score 0):

here is a capybara helper to change an input range based on it's name,
assuming you use [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist):

`def range_select(name, value)
  selector = %-input[type=range][name=\\"#{name}\\"]-
  script = %-$("#{selector}").val(#{value})-
  page.execute_script(script)
end`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [monkey-patched drag_by implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866960/how-do-i-drag-a-jquery-slider-handle-from-within-capybara-and-chromedriver) which could work very well for this if you are using a javascript rangeslider (although it doesn't set a specific value unfortunately, just drags by a specific amount).